# Did I understand this probability problem correctly?

Tags: probability

A typist sometimes makes mistakes by hitting a key to the right or left of the intended key. The probability of hitting a key to the right by accident is 0.01, while the probability of hitting a key to the left by accident is 0.03. The letters W, E, R, and T are adjacent to one another on the standard QWERTY keyboard, and in English they occur with probabilities of (P(W) = 0.0063, P(E) = 0.0999, P(R) = 0.0378, P(T) = 0.0765).

A) What is the probability with which the letter R appears in text typed by this typist?

$$Pr(R_t | E_e)Pr(E_e) + Pr(R_t | T_e)Pr(T_e) + Pr(R_t | \bar{E_e} \cap \bar{T_e})= 0.01\times0.0999 + 0.03\times0.0765 + 0.0765$$

Subscript t means typed, subscript e means error.

B) What is the probability that a letter R appearing in text typed by this typist will be in error?

$$Pr(R_t | E_e)Pr(E_e) + Pr(R_t | T_e)Pr(T_e)= 0.01\times0.0999 + 0.03\times0.0765$$

C) What is the probability that the letter E appearing in the text typed by this typist was intended to be a R?
$$P(E_e | R_t)Pr(R_t)= 0.01 \times 0.0378$$

Comment: Since the typist is mostly accurate, the answer to part A ought to be near $P(R) = 0.0378$. For part B, it looks like you found the probability any letter is an R and was not supposed to be, not the probability the letter was not supposed to be R given the typist did type R. Similar for part C. The meaning of $X_e$ is unclear to me; I'd rather use $X_i$ to mean the intended letter was $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a given spot in the text, call $X_i$ the event that the typist intended letter $X$, and call $X_t$ the event that the typist actually typed letter $X$. Since the typist, we can assume, intended to type some "typical" English words, we have $P(W_i) \approx 0.0063$, $P(E_i) \approx 0.0999$, $P(R_i) \approx 0.0378$, and $P(T_i) \approx 0.0765$.

> A) What is the probability with which the letter R appears in text typed by this typist?

The intended letter could have been E, R, or T. Be sure to take out the probability that the intended letter was R but the typist erred on it.

$$ \begin{align*}
P(R_t) &= P(R_t|R_i) P(R_i) + P(R_t|E_i) P(E_i) + P(R_t|T_i) P(T_i) \\
P(R_t) &= (1-0.01-0.03) \cdot 0.0378 + 0.01 \cdot 0.0999 + 0.03 \cdot 0.0765 \\
P(R_t) &\approx 0.0392
\end{align*} $$

> B) What is the probability that a letter R appearing in text typed by this typist will be in error?

We know the letter typed was R ($R_t)$, and we're looking for the resulting conditional probability that the intended letter was *not* R ($\overline{R_i}$). The result from part (A) can be used in part of the formula.

$$ \begin{align*}
P(\overline{R_i}|R_t) &= \frac{P(\overline{R_i} \cap R_t)}{P(R_t)} = \frac{P(R_t|E_i) P(E_i) + P(R_t|T_i)P(T_i)}{P(R_t)} \\
P(\overline{R_i}|R_t) &\approx \frac{0.01 \cdot 0.0999 + 0.03 \cdot 0.0765}{0.0392} \\
P(\overline{R_i}|R_t) &\approx 0.0752
\end{align*} $$

It might seem odd this result is so large relative to the typist's average error rate $0.04$. The intuitive reason this happens is that E and T are much more common letters than R, so errors where E or T change to R are more common than errors where R changes to E or T. Since more of the errors are in $R_t$, $R_t$ has a larger proportion of errors. (But a caution: intuition is often very wrong about probability results.)

> C) What is the probability that the letter E appearing in the text typed by this typist was intended to be a R?

Here we know the letter typed was E ($E_t$), and we're looking for the conditional probability that R was intended ($R_i$).

$$ \begin{align*}
P(R_i|E_t) &= \frac{P(R_i \cap E_t)}{P(E_t)} = \frac{P(E_t|R_i) P(R_i)}{P(E_t|W_i) P(W_i) + P(E_t|E_i) P(E_i) + P(E_t|R_i) P(R_i)} \\
P(R_i|E_t) &\approx \frac{0.03 \cdot 0.0378}{0.01 \cdot 0.0063 + 0.96 \cdot 0.0999 +  0.03 \cdot 0.0378} \\
P(R_i|E_t) &\approx 0.0117
\end{align*} $$

The $P(E_t)$ in the denominator is found exactly like part (A). An intuitive explanation why this result is small is the reverse of the one for part (B): Since R is a less common letter than E, a small proportion of typed E letters were really supposed to be R letters. (In fact, $P(E_i|E_t)$ is an overwhelming $\sim 0.9877$.)